# Change SelectedIndex of TabControl in MainWindow from Child UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I have a main window with a `TabControl` in it. Each tab contains a `UserControl` associated with it. In one of my `UserControl`, I have a button. When I click the button, I would like to change the `SelectedIndex` of the `TabControl` that is in my main window.

I'm using the MVVM pattern so if possible, I would like to do it in XAML with the Command property on my button.

For example:

```
<Button Content="Switch Tab" Command="SwitchTabCommand" />
```

Thanks in advance my fellow programmers!

**EDIT:**

The window view model:

```
public class CoolViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> Tabs { get; set; }
    public ITabViewModel SelectedTab { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public CoolViewModel()
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>
        {
            new VeryNiceViewModel(),
            new VeryNiceViewModel()
        };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is the code of a UserControl inside a tab:

```
public class VeryCoolViewModel : BaseViewModel, ITabViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    public Test currentSelection { get; set; }
    public string TabHeader { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    ICommand GoToOtherTab { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public GabaritSelecteurViewModel()
    {
        Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>
        {
            new Test { Title = "Title #1" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #2" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #3" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #4" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #5" }
        };

        TabHeader = "Tests";

        GoToOtherTab = new RelayCommand(GoToTab, parameter => true);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void GoToTab(object parameter)
    {
        // I don't know how to tell to the
        // parent window to go to the other tab...
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And here's the XAML for the UserControl (that is inside the TabControl):

```
<Button Content="Go to the other tab" Command="{Binding GoToOtherTab}" />
```

Comment: SelectedIndex is a PITA. It's always easier to use SelectedItem (as long as your instance is one in the ItemsSource collection)

Answer (score 0):

Give the child viewmodel a public property

```
ICommand SwitchTabCommand { get {} set { /* INPC stuff */ } }
```

Bind it to the button's Command property in the usercontrol XAML.

The parent viewmodel can assign a command to the property when it creates the child viewmodel. You can bind a parent vm property to SelectedIndex on the tab control, and the command that the parent creates can set the bound parent viewmodel property.

If you're not going full MVVM and there's no child viewmodel for the usercontrol, make the command property a dependency property of the usercontrol, and bind it to a parent viewmodel command property in the window XAML.

Comment: I tried to do something like that but I never managed to make it work. It's always telling me that either the UserControl or the Window are null. I think it's caused by the order they are being created.